# Scroll text area with "Terms and Conditions" on Hybrid App with Appium

Tags: java, scroll, textarea, appium

I have issue with scrolling "**Terms and Conditions**" text area to the bottom . The app is hybrid,  I gave contex to know that the app is hybrid and its working 
`driver.context("WEBVIEW_********");`
, also the **xpath** to the text area is

```
/html/body/div[2]/ion-nav-view/div/div/div[2]/textarea
```

but I cant find a solution to scroll the text area to the last line with " **All rights reserved** " , so the button " I agree " to be available.

Answer (score 0):

You can swipe in an app with appium using the press method. First find the element to scroll on and then scroll down. E.g. :

```
TouchAction().press(el0).moveTo(el1).release()
```

It also works with coordinates if you wish to use that instead of webelements.

More information on touch actions can be found here : https://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/touch-actions/

Comment: UltimaI try with 
`MobileElement textField = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/ion-nav-view/div/div/div[2]/textarea"));`

`MobileElement text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/ion-nav-view/div/div/div[2]/textarea[@text = 'Any personal information']"));`
  `TouchAction touchAction = new TouchAction(driver);
  touchAction.press(textField).moveTo(text).release();`
but i got error that  "  `no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[2]/ion-nav-view/div/div/div[2]/textarea[@text = 'Any personal information']"}` "

Comment: That means you are unable to find the webelement. If you just want it to work you could try using `coordinates` instead. Then you don't have to bother looking for the element but it's a less flexible solution.

Comment: So there is no solution how to scroll the whole textarea with "Terms and Conditions" ? so to get to the bottom of the whole textarea ? I search for some examples , but couldnt find solution